# Convert QR code to a Nonogram puzzle

Tags: matrix, image-processing, list-manipulation, code-request

I remember there was a GCHQ puzzle where Nonogram was created to generate a QR code in 2015. It was a quite [popular puzzle](https://www.gchq.gov.uk/news-article/christmas-card-cryptographic-twist-charity).

I am wondering if MMA can be used to create a Nonogram from an existing QR code. For example,

```
BarcodeImage["my test", "QR", 10]
```

Is it possible to then create a Nonogram from it? Or even further, if I have a QR  **image**,

[image]

How do I then create the Nonogram?

Thanks.

Comment: You might take a look at this: https://github.com/GalAster/Deus The author appears to have implemented this in the package. I don't really know what all that package does, though.

Comment: If you just take a QR code and generate a Nonogram directly from it, the Nonogram is very likely to not be unique.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming that the image has 1 pixel per for each square of the Nonogram puzzle.

```
Module[
 {
  img = BarcodeImage["my test", "QR", 10],
  data, clue, cluelength, qrdims, nonogram,
  f = ReplaceAll[
     MapAt[
      Total
      , Map[Split, #]
      , {All, All}
      ], 0 -> Nothing
     ] &
  },
 data = ImageData[ColorNegate[img]];
 qrdims = Dimensions[data];
 clue = {f[data], f[Transpose[data]]};
 cluelength = Max[Length /@ Flatten[clue, 1]];
 clue = MapAt[PadLeft[#, cluelength, Null] &, clue, {All, All}];
 nonogram = ConstantArray[Null, (qrdims + {cluelength, cluelength})];
 nonogram[[-First[qrdims] ;; -1, 1 ;; cluelength]] = clue[[1]];
 nonogram[[1 ;; cluelength, -First[qrdims] ;; -1]] = 
  Transpose[clue[[2]]];
 Grid[nonogram
  , ItemSize -> {2, 2}
  , Frame -> {All, All, 
    Flatten@Table[{i, j} -> False, {i, cluelength}, {j, cluelength}]}
  , Spacings -> {0, 0}
  , Background -> {Automatic, Automatic, 
    Rule[{cluelength, cluelength} + #, Black] & /@ Position[data, 1]}
  , Dividers -> {{(cluelength + 1) -> Thick}, {(cluelength + 1) -> 
      Thick}}]
 ]
```

[image]

---

<sub>Code and graphics done in *Mathemathica 11.3.0* on Win7 64</sub>

Comment: Use `Grid[norogram, ItemSize -> {2, 2}, Frame -> All, Spacings -> {0, 0}]` to create the `blank puzzle` then! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

#### [`ComponentMeasurements`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComponentMeasurements.html) and [`MorphologicalComponents`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MorphologicalComponents.html)

```
ClearAll[cf1]
cf1 = ComponentMeasurements[MorphologicalComponents[Image@{#}], "Count"][[All, -1]] & /@ 
   # & /@ ({#, Transpose@#}) &;
```

Using `cf1` with the barcode image in OP:

```
img = BarcodeImage["my test", "QR", 10];

data = 1 - ImageData[img];

cf1 @ data // Panel /@ Grid /@ # & // Row[#, Spacer[20]] &
```

[image]

Alternatively, we can use a combination of  `Length`, `Split` and `DeleteCases` in place of `ComponentMeasurements`:

```
ClearAll[cf2]
cf2 = Length /@ Split[DeleteCases[MorphologicalComponents[Image @ {#}][[1]], 0, 2]] & /@ 
  # & /@ {#, Transpose @ #} &;
cf1 @ data == cf2 @ data
```

> True

#### Visualization using [`ArrayPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArrayPlot.html):

```
counts = cf1 @ data;
labels = {Row[Style[ToString@#, 14, Black] & /@ #, " "] & /@ #, 
     Column[Style[ToString@#, 14, Black] & /@ #, Alignment -> Bottom]& /@ #2} & @@ counts;
ticks = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, #] & /@ labels; 

ArrayPlot[data, FrameTicks -> {{ticks[[1]], None}, {None, ticks[[2]]}}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

#### Visualization using `Grid`:

```
ClearAll[paddedcf, styleItems, nonogram]
paddedcf = Map[ToString, #, {-1}] & @ 
  {#, ArrayPad[Transpose @ #2, {{0}, {First[Length /@ #], 0}}, ""]} & @@
   (PadLeft[#, Automatic, ""] & /@ cf1[#]) &;
styleItems[bg_: Black, ts_: Directive[FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "PanelFontFamily"]] :=
   # /. {0 -> Item[" ", Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Gray], 
     1 -> Item[" ", Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Gray,  Background -> bg], 
     Except["", x_String] :> Item[Style[x, ts], Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Gray]} &;
nonogram[d_] := Join[paddedcf[d][[2]], Join[paddedcf[d][[1]], #, 2]] &;

Row[Grid[styleItems[#] @ nonogram[data] @ data, Spacings -> {0, 0}, 
     ItemSize -> {Scaled@.015, Scaled@.015}] & /@ {White, Red}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

#### [`FlipView`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FlipView.html) to flip between two views

```
{ap1, ap2} =  ArrayPlot[#, Mesh -> All, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400,
     FrameTicks -> {{ticks[[1]], None}, {None, ticks[[2]]}}] & /@ 
 {data, Array[0&, Dimensions @ data]};

FlipView[{ap2, ap1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow useful built-in functions!!!!!

Answer (score 7):

Since OP asked for solutions given any QR image, here is my version. It first standardizes the image using *Mathematica*'s `BarcodeRecognize/BarcodeImage`, then finds the actual pixel size `m` to downsample the matrix to its smallest valid size. I relied here on the string patternmatcher just to get rid of whitespace more easily but one can use of course the `Sequence*` family of functions.

```
i = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnPp9.jpg";
b = BarcodeImage @@ BarcodeRecognize[i, {"Data", "Format"}];
s = ImageData@b /. {0 -> "0", 1 -> " "};
m = Min[StringLength /@ StringSplit@(StringJoin /@ s)];
s = Downsample[s, m];
f = StringLength /@ StringSplit[StringJoin /@ #] &;
{r, c} = MapThread[Transpose@{Range@#1, #3 /@ #2} &,
     {Dimensions@s, {f@s, f@Transpose@s}, {Row, Rotate[Row@#, -Pi/2] &}}];

ArrayPlot[s, ColorRules -> {"0" -> Black, " " -> White}, Mesh -> True, 
     Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {r, c}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]